# Getting JSONException in decoding the JSON string

Tags: android, json

I am trying to decode a JSON response string which is an image encoded.I am getting JSON.typeMismatch error.This is JSON response

```
{
    "0":"9",
    "id":"9",
    "1":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD\/7QCcUGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAIAcAmcAFHN2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\rK\r\nGKFyiEEJ5zs8nX2n7biHRXjaHEufr7tvVV7wPZu3jb06+06lqCnRRF976wd6php\/4mu2HzJUwJHn\r\n+D1gIUR3\/wAkJbefct4GCoGBr6zdXwLjBm9t8nKNHiN6MPxAFpBXRmxgdcXKjFby4zFarYp9ajzt\r\nXHsrVawnUAjtZcLENG9NX7wFrgzzf9hyYVPLRP3nLxsJ+k4eETQjrDgGGAQ9eJQ20h\/4jpMVRaK6\r\nxu2tQaiA3BYikz4JSpu6\/E0DXq3EKl0njVdnFRpSNhB61FVPaKttwfztgj50k1A+5m9UVujGAbH7\r\nTbpqvplxKgQAGxNkEZeOHpOWT76WrRE0kAI0aMeUBoiBUubgviQNrJl1hYCUqKtwhDaou3oWoqr\/\r\nADL\/ANNgsXnkZecXKrJTqsP\/AISVrb9U1wTkHj8CCOA44lfONQIZPvpWWAsvL7TVtBqCfiX2CuQ+\r\n0\/nP4masvEcLNhC+0M2zT72TUFa6EfKZYvIiojsX5lWS5yRXlGsRvAcNMJdmtm+1z9n+YEyZ1v8A\r\nEa1o5r8GOw3b8UtwN1\/HOp+jpLgeHqveLW6xqySCx"
}
```

My android code for decoding is

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://example.com/database/testing.php"); 

HttpResponse response;
try {
     response = client.execute(request);
     String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

     try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(responseStr);
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
         JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(jArray.length()-i-1);
         String img="";//json_data.getString("image");
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), img, 
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
     } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My log shows the following errors

```
 W/System.err(19280): org.json.JSONException: Value         {"id":"5","image":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/4QCYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAACADEBAgAHAAAAJgAAAGmHBAAB\r\nAAAALgAAAAAAAABHb29nbGUAAAQAAJAHAAQAAAAwMjIwCZAHACwAAABkAAAAAqAEAAEAAACAAQAA\r\nA6AEAAEAAAByAQAAAAAAAAoqCAEQARgAIAAoADAAOABAAEgBUABYAGABaAFwAHgBgAEBiAEBkAEB\nx2nba+9uA3AXcit0Q3ZbeHN6i3ynfr+A24L3hROHM4lPi2+Nj4+vkc+T8\r\n5YTmDeaW5x\/nqegy6LzpRunQ6lvq5etw6\/vshu0R7ZzuKO6070DvzPBY8OXxcvH\/8ozzGfOn9DT0\r\nwvVQ9d72bfb794r4Gfio+Tj5x\/pX+uf7d\/wH\/Jj9Kf26\/kv+3P9t\/\/9kZXNjAAAAAAAAAC5JRUMg\r\nNjE5NjYtMi0xIERlZmF1bHQgUkdCIENvbG91ciBTcGFjZSAtIHNSR0IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\r\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

 05-09 18:19:02.196: W/System.err(19280):   at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch
  (JSON.java:111)
 05-09 18:19:02.196: W/System.err(19280):   at org.json.JSONArray.<init>

 (JSONArray.java:91)
 05-09 18:19:02.196: W/System.err(19280):   at org.json.JSONArray.<init>

  (JSONArray.java:103)
   05-09 18:19:02.196: W/System.err(19280):     at        com.threepixels.tester.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
   05-09 18:19:02.196: W/System.err(19280):     at   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
      05-09 18:19:02.206: W/System.err(19280):  at andro    id.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        05-09 18:19:02.206: W/System.err(19280):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
     05-09 18:19:02.206: W/System.err(19280):   at   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
```

Comment: please post your full JSON response.

Comment: I don't see any array in your json... as I can see it's just a simple JSONObject... does it throw an error at JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(responseStr);??

Comment: no error at JSONArray

Comment: @don well the json you've posted is not an array for sure. It's an dictionary with 3 keys which are 0, id and 1. which line throws the error exactly?

Comment: Did you try to validate json response? As posted, it seems to be truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Your Json is a JsonObject not an array, so basically changing this:

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(responseStr);
```

to

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(responseStr);
```

should fix it. Give it a try and let us know